# sort by flexible criteria

Tags: r, algorithm, sorting

I am building a product recommendation engine (in R) using collaborative filtering. To keep more profitable items at the top of the recommendations, we have developed a **flexible** business rule that looks like figure 1. The business rule should be used to sort the recommender output.

```
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
| Sort Priority | Level 1  | Level 2         |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
| 1             | Brand    | Versatile Foods |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          | Agro            |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          | Specialty Foods |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          |                 |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
| 2             | Category | Dairy           |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          | Produce         |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          | Seafood         |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          |                 |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
| 3             | Seasonal | Y               |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          | N               |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
            figure 1
```

> ***Business Rules:*** When sorting the table, the Brand column should take priority over
>   Category which should take priority over Seasonal. This is decided by the value of the column sort priority.
>
> When sorting within the Brand column, Versatile Foods takes priority over Agro and Agro
>   over Specialty Foods. 
>   If the value in the brand column does not appear
>   in the rule, the value(s) must be sorted alphabetically.
>   The same sorting logic should apply to every entry in the rule definition.

As the recommendation algorithm evolves. the business rules can be changed/edited to have less or more levels. For e.g. an additional level1 entry may be added in the future, say, Type (Kosher, Vegan, Halal) etc. The rules will then look as below:

```
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
| Sort Priority | Level 1  | Level 2         |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
| 1             | Brand    | Versatile Foods |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          | Agro            |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          | Specialty Foods |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          |                 |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
| 2             | Category | Dairy           |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          | Produce         |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          | Seafood         |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          |                 |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
| 3             | Type     | Kosher          |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          | Halal           |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          | Vegan           |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          |                 |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
| 4             | Seasonal | Y               |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|               |          | N               |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
            figure 2
```

I need help in building a script in R that will sort the above table (loaded into a dataframe) by the aforementioned business rules. 
The real problem that I want to solve is that I don't want to change the code every time a new entry is added to the rule.

The input data (output by the recommendation engine) will be something of this sort (figure 3).

```
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| SKU | Brand           | Category | Seasonal |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 1   | Versatile Foods | Dairy    | Y        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 2   | Agro            | Produce  | Y        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 3   | Specialty Foods | Seafood  | N        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 4   | Agro            | Produce  | N        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 5   | Specialty Foods | Organic  | Y        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 6   | Agro            | Meat     | N        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 7   | Versatile Foods | Seafood  | N        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 8   | USA Bread       | Bakery   | Y        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 9   | Specialty Foods | Seafood  | N        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 10  | Versatile Foods | Seafood  | N        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
                  figure 3
```

With the rule definition as in figure 1, the output of the script should be just like the below table. 

Notice how Brand = USA bread which does not occur in the business rule was placed at the bottom of the sorted list.

Also, for items 4 and 6, the record with category = 'Produce' was placed above the record with category = 'Meat' as the entry 'Meat' was not found in the business rules but 'Produce' was.

```
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| SKU | Brand           | Category | Seasonal |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 1   | Versatile Foods | Dairy    | Y        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 7   | Versatile Foods | Seafood  | N        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 10  | Versatile Foods | Seafood  | N        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 2   | Agro            | Produce  | Y        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 4   | Agro            | Produce  | N        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 6   | Agro            | Meat     | N        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 3   | Specialty Foods | Seafood  | N        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 9   | Specialty Foods | Seafood  | N        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 5   | Specialty Foods | Organic  | Y        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 8   | USA bread       | Bakery   | Y        |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
                 figure 4
```

Comment: I have edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: I have edited my question. Can somebody remove from hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use factor coding to order things however you want. For example:

```
> lvl <- c('Versatile Foods', 'Agro', 'Specialty Foods')
> lvl <- append(lvl, sort(setdiff(unique(df$Brand), lvl)))
> 
> df$Brand <- factor(df$Brand, levels=lvl)
> 
> lvl <- c("Dairy", "Produce", "Seafood")
> lvl <- append(lvl, sort(setdiff(unique(df$Category), lvl)))
> 
> df$Category <- factor(df$Category, levels=lvl)
> 
> df$Seasonal <- factor(df$Seasonal, levels=c('Y', 'N'))
> 
> 
> df[order(df$Brand, df$Category, df$Seasonal), ]
   SKU           Brand Category Seasonal
1    1 Versatile Foods    Dairy        Y
7    7 Versatile Foods  Seafood        N
10  10 Versatile Foods  Seafood        N
2    2            Agro  Produce        Y
4    4            Agro  Produce        N
6    6            Agro  Produce        N
3    3 Specialty Foods  Seafood        N
9    9 Specialty Foods  Seafood        N
5    5 Specialty Foods  Organic        Y
8    8       USA Bread   Bakery        Y
```

Comment: Thanks. This will solve my problem partially. However, the business rule is dynamic and may have more levels e.g. Type (Kosher, Vegan, Halal) etc.

Comment: I thought you wanted the the extra things sorted alpha at the end?

Comment: I am sorry if my comment is not clear. I mean to say that we might have a change in business rules where we might also add Type (Kosher, Vegan, Halal) at the end of the rule. I don't want to hard code the factors in the df[order(df$Brand, df$Category, df$Seasonal, df$type), ] as the list can be pretty much changing all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I can read the columns dynamically and get around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This approach involves defining a sort rank table and then performing sort using the new columns after merging with the main table.

```
library(dplyr)
rank <- data_frame(Brand = c('Versatile Foods','Agro','Specialty Foods'),
                   Brand_rank = c(1,2,3))
df <- left_join(df, rank, on="Brand") %>%
    arrange(Brand_rank, Brand, Category, Seasonal) %>%
    select(-Brand_rank)
df
# A tibble: 10 × 4
#    SKU           Brand Category Seasonal
#    <dbl>           <chr>    <chr>    <chr>
#1      1 Versatile Foods    Dairy        Y
#2      7 Versatile Foods  Seafood        N
#3     10 Versatile Foods  Seafood        N
#4      4            Agro  Produce        N
#5      6            Agro  Produce        N
#6      2            Agro  Produce        Y
#7      5 Specialty Foods  Organic        Y
#8      3 Specialty Foods  Seafood        N
#9      9 Specialty Foods  Seafood        N
#10     8       USA Bread   Bakery        Y
```